# Open the most recent folder in a directory

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a script that will open the latest folder in a directory.

The name of the folder will be different each month (01-Jan, 02-Feb e.t.c). The below seems to find the latest folder, but I get error File not found when I add in Shell "explorer.exe" & "" & strFullFldrPath, vbNormalFocus to open the folder.

This is what I have so far.

```
Sub GetLatestFolder()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fldrRoot As Folder
Dim SubFld As Folder

Dim strFolderName As String
Dim strFullFldrPath As String


Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set fldrRoot = fso.GetFolder("\\Hbeu.adroot.hsbc\dfsroot\GB002\RRU\DTCC EU Reports\ETD\")

For Each SubFld In fldrRoot.SubFolders
strFolderName = SubFld.Name
strFullFldrPath = fldrRoot & "\" & SubFld.Name

Shell "explorer.exe" & "" & strFullFldrPath, vbNormalFocus
    Exit For
Next SubFld

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to run `"explorer.exeC:\WHATEVER"` i.e. your missing a space between the executable and its argument. 

Quotes are a good idea to accommodate paths with spaces.

```
Shell "explorer.exe" & " """ & strFullFldrPath & """, vbNormalFocus
```

What you have does not *guarantee* the latest folder is always first, you should apply some logic based on the name or load all directories and sort.